# What are current and finalized blocks in the substrate blockchain node template?

Tags: substrate

I have a question regarding : **substrate-node-template** (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).

I have run the node together with the frontend and I noticed there is some activity on the blockchain event without interaction from the user. Where is this activity configured in the source code?

What are **current** and **finalized** blocks? Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node template generates blocks even if there is no transactions happening.
I would encourage you to go through this section of the Knowledge Base to understand how consensus and block generation works https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/advanced/consensus#consensus-in-substrate

EDIT: if you are curious in how you can make your node to only generate blocks when there are transactions happening [this](https://substrate.dev/recipes/kitchen-node.html) is a good resource.

Now, as a short answer for what are current and finalized blocks, the ones under the *current/best* name are the ones that have been authored. And the finalized ones, are the ones which the consensus mechanism consider final.

You can find a formal definition of the protocols in web3 foundation research page.

- [Block Production](https://w3f-research.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polkadot/block-production.html)
- [Finality](https://w3f-research.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polkadot/finality.html)